# addObject NSMutableDictionary to a NSMutableArray only storing pointers not values?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am using the following code:

```
NSMutableArray *data;
NSMutableDictionary *item;

item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


for (int i=1; i <= 3; i++) {
    NSString *fn = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"firstname%@", [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", i]];
    NSString *ln = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"lastname%@", [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", i]];

    [item setObject:fn forKey:@"firstname"];
    [item setObject:ln forKey:@"lastname"];

    [data addObject:item];
}

NSLog(@"%@", data);
```

The result is not firstname1, lastname1, firstname2, lastname2, firstname3, lastname3 but:

```
{
    firstname = firstname3;
    lastname = lastname3;
},
    {
    firstname = firstname3;
    lastname = lastname3;
},
    {
    firstname = firstname3;
    lastname = lastname3;
}
```

I am missing something?

Comment: Why would you expect anything different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new dictionary each iteration:

```
NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=1; i <= 3; i++) {
    NSMutableDictionary *item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSString *fn = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"firstname%@", [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", i]];
    NSString *ln = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"lastname%@", [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", i]];

    [item setObject:fn forKey:@"firstname"];
    [item setObject:ln forKey:@"lastname"];

    [data addObject:item];
}

NSLog(@"%@", data);
```

Your code was creating an array with multiple references to the same dictionary, where the last iteration was setting the value for all those dictionaries.

Comment: You saved my day! its getting harder to find Objective C specialists!

Answer (score -1):

addObject stores a reference to the object and increases the retain count. That's dangerous if you add a mutable object, since the mutable object can be changed further while it is in your array or dictionary.

The simplest way to avoid this is to call addObject:[myMutableObject copy]. If myMutableObject is indeed mutable, then an immutable copy is made and added to your array or dictionary. If it is not mutable, then copy doesn't actually do anything but returns the same object - clearly whether you use the original or a copy doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I don't think this addresses the confusion felt by the questioner.

Comment: I'm completely sure that this addresses the Q of the questioner.